# Setting child element to aria-expanded="true" when parent contains class="active"

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I want to set a child element to `aria-expanded="true"` when its parent contains a class `active`:

```
<li class="dropdown active">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="true">
        Section 4 
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class=""><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This code comes from a example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy2&stacked=h)

When in that example, I scroll down to section 4-1 and 4-2 I would like the dropdown to open up. I have tried several things, but I have not found a working solution.

Comment: Does the li become active on a click event?

Comment: @K.G The li becomes active when its scrolled over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is to add the class open to the active drop down, the effect you want has nothing to do with aria-expanded=true:

Use this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ( $( ".dropdown" ).is( ".active" ) ) {
     $( ".dropdown.active" ).addClass("open");
}
else
{
$( ".dropdown" ).removeClass("open");
}

});
```

Comment: Your awnser comes the closest to what i need, could you setup a fiddle for this? It does not seem te work with the example code that i posted in the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i didnt manage to get it to work, but with your snippet it does!

Answer (score 0):

If it on a click event, use something similar to this.

```
$('body').on('click', 'li.dropdown', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).children().attr('aria-expanded', true);
  }
});
```

or

```
$('body').on('click', 'li.dropdown', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).find('a.dropdown-toggle').attr('aria-expanded', true);
  }
});
```